# Why do I get wrong time Data from DB when fetching using java?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, datetime, mariadb

So I am writing an app in java using swing framework that has a time in and time log feature.

I am using **Eclipse** IDE.
**JDK Version:** 14.0.2
**DATABASE:** MariaDB

I do not have a problem inserting my data into the database. It stores the correct data when I try querying in my db. For example when I try fetching all-time record of employee 1.

```
MariaDB [edpm]> select * from timerecord where Employee_empID = 1;
+-------+----------------+----------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| recID | Employee_empID | timeIn   | timeOut  | date       | onLeave | isHoliday | isWeekend | leaveType | computed |
+-------+----------------+----------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|     1 |          00001 | 10:49:58 | 15:27:16 | 2020-12-01 |    NULL |      NULL |      NULL |      NULL |     NULL |
|     3 |          00001 | 08:39:32 | 08:39:43 | 2020-12-03 |    NULL |      NULL |      NULL |      NULL |     NULL |
|     4 |          00001 | 17:55:48 | NULL     | 2020-12-10 |    NULL |      NULL |      NULL |      NULL |     NULL |
|     5 |          00001 | 07:37:15 | 19:03:00 | 2021-01-18 |    NULL |         0 |         0 |      NULL |     NULL |
|     6 |          00001 | 07:52:44 | 18:15:00 | 2021-01-19 |    NULL |         0 |         0 |      NULL |     NULL |
|     7 |          00001 | 07:28:00 | 18:33:00 | 2021-01-21 |    NULL |         0 |         0 |      NULL |     NULL |
|     8 |          00001 | 07:46:58 | 18:43:00 | 2021-01-22 |    NULL |         0 |         0 |      NULL |     NULL |
|    10 |          00001 | 07:40:36 | 17:00:00 | 2021-01-26 |    NULL |         0 |         0 |      NULL |     NULL |
|    11 |          00001 | 07:29:54 | 18:30:57 | 2021-01-28 |    NULL |         0 |         0 |      NULL |     NULL |
|    13 |          00001 | 07:58:06 | 17:41:00 | 2021-01-29 |    NULL |         0 |         0 |      NULL |     NULL |
+-------+----------------+----------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

The problem is when I am fetching the data using my code, the time data is advanced 30 mins.

These are the results:
[wrong time data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIyHl.png)

This is my code in fetching my data.

```
public static ArrayList<TimeRecord> getRecord(int empID, Date from, Date to){
        conn = DB_Connect.connect();

        TimeRecord tr = new TimeRecord();

        ArrayList<TimeRecord> results = new ArrayList<TimeRecord>();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM timerecord WHERE Employee_empID = '" + empID + "' AND date BETWEEN '"+ from
                        +"' AND '" + to + "';";

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()) {
                tr.setDate(rs.getDate("date"));
                tr.setIn(rs.getTimestamp("timeIn"));
                tr.setOut(rs.getTimestamp("timeOut"));

                if(rs.getBoolean("isHoliday"))
                    tr.setHoliday(true);
                else
                    tr.setHoliday(false);

                if(rs.getBoolean("isWeekend"))
                    tr.setWeekend(true);
                else
                    tr.setWeekend(false);

                results.add(tr);
                conn.close();
            }
            return results;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I also tried `getTime()` but the results are the same.

Any idea why when fetching through `ResultSet.getTime()` or `ResultSet.getTimestamp()` my time data will change and advance 30 mins?
Or any suggestion on how to fix this? I am out of ideas for now.

**PS:** Please bear with my code, I know there is much to improve for its optimization. I am still learning java.

Comment: TimeRecord class, is a custom class or imported from some source ? in any case, you should look at the implementation of both setIn and setOut

Have you tried debuging it ? whats the result of rs.getTimestamp("timeIn") ?

Comment: TimeRecord is a custom class that contains variables that can store the data seen on timerecord table in my database.
I did try debugging it, and the data is still changed to 30 mins advanced. I am trying to look into timezone settings.

Comment: good, but whats the implementation ? what are the input parameters, is there any further parsing/manipulation ? or its just a bean

Comment: setIn and setOut is just a setter for a variable in my TimeRecord class. No more further parsing and manipulation. That's why I am confused. It's like getting data from DB and the result is changed/added 30 mins to the data.

Comment: than it is the timestamp method of the resultset, just create a custom method, where you give the date and time column information, and use timestamp which accepts (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) format, in this case you should be ok

Comment: Alright, I will try that. Thank you @ConstantinTrepadus

Comment: What is the data type of column `timeIn` and column `timeOut` in database table `timerecord`? Is it [TIMESTAMP](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/)?

Comment: @Abra I used Time as a data type in the database. Then in my code, I tried ResultSet `getTime()` and `getTimestamp()` which has the same result: data is advanced 30 mins.

Comment: I'm guessing that it has to do time zones. What is the MariaDB time zone? What is the time zone of the java code when you run it?

Comment: There are [Half Hour and 45-Minute Time Zones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html)!

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`

Comment: Thank you @RickJames 
Do you know what time zone is the eclipse/java is using as default? or any way to check it?